# can only login on Oracle with sys or system account

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I just installed 12cR2 on centOS6.6.I logged in with sys account as follows:

```
sqlplus sys/syspasswd@dbcenter/pdbcenter as sysdba
```

then,I created a user as follows:

```
SQL> CREATE USER test identified by test
SQL> GRANT CONNECT,RESOURCE,CREATE SESSION TO TEST
```

sqlplus reported user create with no errors.but when I try to login with test account,I got error:

```
sqlplus test/test@dbcenter/pdbcenter

ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

What could be the problem?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check if user is listed in dba_users/all_users view. If not, then it might be that you have created the user in older oracle version and now trying to login with that in newer oracle12c. Confirm the port and ORACLE_HOME path listed in your TNS Entry is correct, as you mentioned while installing oracle.

Comment: In the answer an easy connect was used therefore TNS entries are irrelevant.